# Non homogenous equation- Plotting a graph of y against x

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, graphing-functions

> Given the following equations:
> $$x'=-x+y-1$$
> $$y'=-x-y+3$$
> When $t=0$, $x=0$ and $y=3$
> Find the general solution for $x$ and $y$ in terms of $t$.

**Draw a graph of $y$ against $x$ for values of $t$ >0. Describe what happens as $t$ approaches infinity**.

I have found the general solution for $x$ and $y$ to be:
$$x(t)=e^{-t}  (A cos⁡t+B sin ⁡t)+1$$
$$y(t)=e^{-t} (A cost+B sint)+2$$

Applying the initial conditions the particular solutions are:
$$x(t)=e^{-t}  (- cos⁡t+ sin ⁡t)+1$$
$$y(t)=e^{-t} ( cost+ sint)+2$$.

Can someone please help verify that this is correct so far and help me with how to proceed in graphing this and explaining the resultant graph.

Comment: I've done this and got the correct answer from the phase plane portrait and parametric plot using the inital equations. However, when I plot the final particular solutions the intercept of the lines lies at ~(1.1,2.4) which is clearly above (1,2). Is this correct or is there an error in my particular solutions?

Comment: The interception of which lines? Also, keep in mind that $e^{-t}$ tends to $0$ as $t$ tends to $\infty$ but is never $0$ for any finite $t$. So since you plot your solutions for $t\in(0,T)$ and $T<\infty$, your solutions will never reach $(1,2)$, but approach it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have explicit solutions, you can use one of the many graph plotter websites. To determine the behavior as $t\rightarrow\infty$, it might help to first look into the behaviors of $t\mapsto e^{-t}$, $t\mapsto \cos(t)$, $t\mapsto\sin(t)$ as $t$ approaches infinity and you should be able to figure a behavior for the product of those elementary functions.